# Water resistant MacBook or Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

My kid has so far poured my large mug of coffee into our Air, then barfed on it (yes, it got inside) and now another cup of coffee. That last one finally killed it. Apple says the mobo is gone and it will cost more to fix than its worth.

So now I'm going to either get another Air or maybe just the Book. In either case, can someone offer any suggestions on how to make it even slightly more liquid resistant?

Comment: You could take the fairly obvious precaution of not letting small children anywhere near expensive electronics.

Comment: You don't have kids, do you? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a keyboard protector to make the laptop slightly more resistant to spills.

For example a product like the [Moshi ClearGuard Keyboard Protector](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/TV901LL/A/moshi-clearguard-keyboard-protector-for-aluminum-macbook-and-macbook-pro).

Comment: I have been looking at some of these, but they universally have bad reviews. They seem to collect dust while not actually staying in place.

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no alternatives.